# Why are there restrictions for women in Hindu temples (in general)?

Tags: belief, culture, women

I am here talking in general & not related to a specific temple or place. Why are women not allowed to touch an idol of God or come near it? Is it related to their menstrual cycle? If so, why is it considered impure because of it?

Comment: Related [Why women are not allowed to enter sabarimala?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10116/3500) , [Why women are not allowed to offer prayers at Shingnapur Shani Temple?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9661/3500) and [Why are menstruating women (at least in the Brahmin community) asked to be separate from the family for three days?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8/3500).

Comment: Somewhat similar question [References from scriptures about prohibition of menstruating women from temples, pujas etc](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10132/3500)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During menses women are said to have an "irreversible religious impurity".

So it means, no matter what they do (like bathing, or achamana etc) they can't purify themselves in those days.

That's why their visit to temples or worshiping are considered  futile and hence the restriction.

A same kind "irreversible religious impurity" also applies during the period of "Osaucham" to the members of a family where a death (or birth) has taken place.

Members of that family during that period are also prohibited from participating in any kind of religious activities irrespective of whether  they are male or female members.

And, of course the question "why such impurity occurs?" can't have rational answers.

Comment: @Ankit Sharma: What's Osaucham?

Comment: @VarunKrish I don't know. I am just an editor, ask Rickross.

Comment: @Varun Krish Asaucham (or Ousacham) is a religious impurity that occurs when somebody dies in a family or even when a birth takes place.When someone died its(the impurity) called-Mritakam  and if someone is born its called-Sutakam.In both cases the family members are prohibited from performing religious duties/activities like Puja etc.