# Celebrating festival while menstruation

Tags: scripture, rituals, festivals

I red in devi baghavatham that a rajaswala is not allowed to cook food and if does, treated as sin.

My doubt is whether is it allowed to celebrate festival during menstruation?

For example, today is [Karva Chaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karva_Chauth), is it allowed for a rajaswala to do fast and watching moon through sieve for husband? Will it be a sin if rajaswala does it?

Refer authentic text if it denies/ allows a rajaswala celebrating festivals (doing fast, praying gods etc.,)

Comment: Related http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8/why-are-menstruating-women-at-least-in-the-brahmin-community-asked-to-be-separ

Comment: They are not allowed to do anything related to religious activity. Fasts, Special Poojas, are not allowed. A rajaswala is not allowed even doing Nitya Puja also. She should rest in a isolated room.

Comment: During mensuration, women are not allowed to do anything. Why? Because it is not right to ask a those who are already in "Pain" to work. Is it?

Comment: It is not allowed for her to perform any religious activity. So poojas, kadva chauth etc are not allowed. She also must not come in contact with communal water containers, clothes used by others, food to be consumed by others.

Answer (score 5):

During courses a woman is considered very "impure"(the degree of impurity is described in one of the verses given below).The Scriptures even say that touching their husbands during those days is an offence.Participating in religious activity of any kind is strictly prohibited,which should only resume once the courses are over.

Following are some verses from Parashara Smriti(Chapter 7):

> 15. A woman in her monthly courses, is restored to purity after having washed herself, on the fourth day. When the courses actually cease,
>       however, **it is then that she should engage herself in the
>       performance of the rites due to the manes and the gods.**
> 16. **As long as the menstrual fluid continues to flow, so long the acts and doings of the woman cannot be clean.** When the courses
>       cease, the woman becomes fit to have intercourse with, and she may
>       then employ herself in the household duties.
> 17. On the first day that the blood begins to flow, the woman is comparable to a female Chandala ; on the second, she is like a
>       Brahmanicide ; on the third, she may be likened to a washerwoman. On
>       the fourth day, * however, she is entirely pure.

[image]

If some woman had done a sankalpa(taken a vow) for doing a prolonged Vrata which is extended over months(like say 16 monday fasts etc),then she can skip  fasts on the days which coincide with her courses without breaking the vow(but she should complete as many fasts as she promised during taking the vow).

**Update-** From the [Vasistha Dharma Sutras](http://www.astrojyoti.com/vasisthadharmasutras.htm):

> 5. **A woman in her courses is impure during three (days and) nights.**
> 6. (During that period) she shall not apply collyr ium to her eyes, nor anoint (her body), **nor bathe in water**; she shall sleep on the
>      ground; she shall not sleep in the day-time, nor touch the fire, no r
>      make a rope, **nor clean her teeth**, nor eat meat, nor look at the
>      planets, nor smile, nor busy herself with (house-hold affairs), nor
>      run; she shall drink out of a large vessel, or out of her joined hands, or out of a copper vessel.

Now,as you should be knowing,before participating in a religious rite(including a fast )  purity of body is the first requirement.So,bathing is a must.

But, as you can see both bathing as well as brushing of teeth are prohibited on those 3 days.Needless to say,that performance of vratas or engaging in any kind of religious activities will not thus be possible on those 3 days for any woman.

Comment: In those days the society treated women like those with less significance. Hence, you would find the comparisons like in point 17 in above answer.

Comment: @ParagBaji One,you should not judge scriptures from an emotional pov because truth is beyond emotion.And,two u should also not judge a scripture by reading only one (among 100) of its verses.Because then chances r u'll be misled..One shud read the whole scripture before coming to a conclusion...Point 17 only mentions the degree of impurity that women carry in those days.No question of praising or degrading.those are just plain facts.In our Shastras its stated that except on those 3 days women are ever pure and nothing of that sort is being said for the men.So,its certainly not the way u think.

Comment: agreed. Well said mate.

Comment: @Rickross its sad that you are still believing such spurious verses which talk bad about women. this is not a sign of a shakta...

Comment: @RakeshJoshi These rules are universal..They shd be followed by each sect..also i don't think that thrs anything in the verses that are insulting to women..In those 3 days the womenfolk are getting rid of their sins and hence they remain impure..in the remaining days they r ever pure..all Smritis mention the same thing..

Comment: @Rickross so adjectives like chandalini is not insulting ? bravo !!

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I think that is an way to describe the extent of impurity.nothing more..

Comment: @Rickross i will quote some scriptures soon ...

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Ok..

Comment: @Rickross please also quote such verses describing man's impurities ?