# Where is it mentioned about story and reason for women periods (menstruation) in our religious texts?

Tags: women, indra

I came across a story in which once Brihaspati left Indra and due to that Indra appointed another Brahmin for a Yagna and since he was half Asur (born from Asur mother, therefore, he made Yagna  Aahuti in favour of Asuras. When Indra came to know of this he killed him and but then Indra got the sin of Bramha-Hatya. This story I have read many times and I think the one killed was Sage Twastha.

But the story doesn't end here, I have read somewhere now that Indra did Penance for 1 lakh years but still to be free from the sin he has to pass it to Plants, Water, Earth and Women. They all accepted to take away part of his sin and get a boon in favour of that. It was mentioned that due to this reason the women have periods every month.

Here is the summary text that I have read about this:

भागवत पुराण के अनुसर एक बार ब्रहस्पती जो देवताओं के गुरु थे, इंद्र से नाराज़ हो गए. इस के चलते असुरों ने देवलोक पर आक्रमण कर दिया और इंद्र को अपनी गद्दी छोड कर भागना पडा. इंद्र मदद मंगने के लीए ब्रह्मा के पास पहुँचे. ब्रह्मा जी ने इंद्र को बताया की उसे एक ब्रह्म-ज्ञानी की सेवा करके ब्रहसपती को वापस प्रसन्न करना पड़ेगा.
इंद्र एक ब्रहम-ज्ञानी की सेवा में जी-जान से जुट गया. लेकिन उस ज्ञानी की माता एक असुर थी इसलिए उसके मन में असुराओं के लीए एक विशेष स्थान था. हवन की सामग्री जो देवताओं को चढाई जाती है, वह ज्ञानी उसे असुरों को चढा रहा था, यह देख इंद्र के गुस्से का ठिकाना ना रहा और उसने उस ब्रह्म-ज्ञानी की हत्या कर डाली.
क्योंकी इंद्र ने उस ब्रह्म-ज्ञानी को अपना गुरु माना था इसलिए इंद्र के उपर ब्रह्म-हत्या-पताखा का पाप आ गाया. ये पाप एक भयानक राक्षशी के रूप में इंद्र का पिछा करने लगा. किसी तराह इंद्र ने खुद को एक फुल के अंदर छुपाया और एक लाख साल तक भगवान विष्णु की तपस्या की. विष्णु की कृपा से वह उस राक्षशी से तो मुक्ति पा गया पर ब्रह्म-हत्या का पाप अब भी इंद्र के सर था.
अपने सर से यह पाप हटाने के लीए और अपना राज्य वापस पाने के लिये इंद्र ने पेड, जल, भूमि और स्त्री से अपने पाप का थोडा थोडा हिस्सा लेने का आग्रह किया. सभी राज़ी हो गए पर इस शर्त पर की इंद्र का पाप लेने पर उनको कोई वरदन भी मिलना चाहिये. सबसे पहले पेडों के राजा ने एक-चोथाई पाप लिया जिसके कारण पेडों के तनों अक्सर रिस्ते हैं. वरदान स्वरूप इंद्र ने कहा की कोई भी पेड अपने आपका दुअबरा उगा सकता है/जीवित कर सकता है.
दूसरे नंबर पर था जल. जल ने इंद्र का पाप लिया तो पश्चाताप स्वरूप जो झाग/बुलबुले पानी के उपर बन जाता हैं वे अपवित्र हो गये. वरदान स्वरूप इंद्र ने जल को सब चीज़ों को पवित्र करने की शक्ति दे डी. यही कारण हैं की पूजा पाठ के कामों में जल का इस्तमाल होता है. फिर नंबर था भूमि का, पाप लेने के कारण भूमि की कई हिस्से बंजर हो गाए और वरदान स्वरूप धरती पर आई कोई भी चोट हमेशा भर जाती है.
फिर स्त्री की बारी आई. इंद्र का बचा हुआ पाप लेने के कारण, पश्चाताप स्वरूप हर महीन स्त्रीयों को मासिक धर्म होता है और वरदान के रूप में इंद्र ने कहा की "महिलायें, पुरुषों से कई गुना ज्यादा काम का आनंद उठाएंगी. हिन्दू धर्म के अनुसर मासिक धर्म के दौरान महिलायें ब्रह्म-हत्या का पाप ढो रही होती हैं, अपने गुरु की हत्या का पाप और गुरु के बीना भगवान नहीं मिलते इसलिए महिलाओं को मन्दिर नहीं जना चाहिये.

Can anyone please tell me where is the latter part of story mentioned? The story says it is from Bhagavata purana, but can anyone please let me know the exact line no.s where this is mentioned.

Edit: As I stated in comments, can anyone please confirm whether it is written in texts that this is the reason why women are not allowed in temples/religious ceremonies or customs during their mensuration periods.

Comment: See this post : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17616/were-women-cursed-with-menstruation/17617#17617

Comment: @Rickross, thanks for the link, but I actually wanted to see it in the texts that because of this burden of sin, women are not allowed in temples, etc in their mensuration period. You know there is lot of debate going on on this in Shani temple, etc so my reason of asking was first to verify whether this story is true and secondly to verify whether this is a valid reason specified in texts banning the entry of women in temples. Once again thanks for your link.

Comment: Some scriptures like the Smritis, Puranas tell us that since women agreed to take a share of Indra's sins, hence during those days they will be impure. Its like sin flowing out of them and making them pure again. But since u know that the first prerequisite of visiting temples, participating in a religious act is purity hence the women should not do these things during those days. [Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15519/4732) is an answer you will be interested in.

Comment: @Aby I will soon post about the question.

Comment: If menses is related to that story then it would mean that women did not menstruate before that incident which is biologically impossible !!!

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Yeah, agree, this whole story in SB must be an interpolation best categorized as fiction.

Comment: the vedic story must be properly interpret ..

Comment: If menses is a symbol of sin then it would mean that women who do not attain puberty are pious souls and have no punishment of sins, they should be punyaatmas but  absence of menses is a disease "amnorhhea"

Comment: @Aby - Thanks , I have voted to close question as duplicate, but if you want the answer   abt.entry to the women in temples in those days and other things pls. highlight that part as main question. I will retract my vote accordingly.