# How are trees sharing Indra's guilt?

Tags: puranas, indra, sin

As given in puranic stories, Indra shared His guilt of killing a Brahmana among Women, Trees, Water and Earth.

The below verse tells [the guilt shared by trees](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/9/8):

> तुर्यं छेदविरोहेण वरेण जगृहुर्द्रुमाः
>   
> तेषां निर्यासरूपेण ब्रह्महत्या प्रदृश्यते ॥ ६.९.८ ॥
>   
> In return for Indra’s benediction that their branches and twigs would grow back when trimmed, the trees accepted one fourth of the reactions for killing a brāhmaṇa. **These reactions are visible in the flowing of sap from trees.** [Therefore one is forbidden to drink this sap.]

I didn't bold "therefore one is forbidden to drink this sap" because it's not there in Sanskrit.

1. From [this website](https://www.thespruce.com/when-a-tree-bleeds-sap-3269770):

   > Much like the veins in our body, the tree's vascular system transports sap. This is a sugary liquid filled with water and nutrients that are carried throughout the tree via the phloem and xylem. **Its purpose is to carry those nutrients from the leaves where it is produced down to the roots and other parts of the tree to promote healthy growth.** If a cut is made in the trunk or a branch, the sap may start oozing out.
2. [The use of Indian Bedellium tree's sap](https://hubpages.com/health/Medicine-From-Tree-Sap) is given as:

   > **Guggul, sap from the Indian Bedellium tree (Commiphora mukul ), was used in Ayurvedic medicine in India for at least 2,000 years for a variety of ailments, including supporting normal joint function.** Modern researchers have found it to be effective in controlling cholesterol and triglyceride levels in the body. Guggul is still commonly used for its anti-inflammatory, pain killing, rejuvenative, detoxifying, immune system modulating, antioxidant and fat burning properties, while also protecting against ailments, such as the common cold and various other skin, eye and dental infections

   Further, the conclusion section of it says:

   > It is ... **The sap can be used as a home remedy or you can even consider drinking it for the nutrition it provides.** There is a high probability that it may become a necessity to investigate other sources of nutrition in the near future.
3. And [this](https://www.thereadystore.com/survival-tips/16270/the-many-survival-uses-of-pine-sap/) website says:

   > **THINK OF PINE SAP AS MOTHER NATURE’S BAND -AID**
   >   
   > Because pine sap is a sticky amber glob that hardens, it’ll keep germs out, boost cell immunity and act as an anti-inflammatory on open wounds. Make sure that you properly clean or flush the area before applying pine sap.
   >   
   > **COUGH MEDICINE & CHEWING GUM**
   >   
   > Since pine sap is a natural antibacterial, it will stop coughing, slowly kill bacterial infections, and improve breathing when sick.

The above are three examples of the uses of sap inside a tree and it's medicinal use for human. There could be many other tree's sap uses given in Ayurveda.

**Effect of curses for women, river and earth are :**
During menstrual cycle women are resisted to enter into temples and perform poojas, during the two Hindu months Sravana and Bhadra [the rivers](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18367/when-does-all-water-become-impure-as-a-result-of-sharing-indras-guilt-of-brahmi) are considered as impure in the scriptures and the deserts on the earth.

My question: I didn't understand in what way the trees are sharing the guilt? Because sap has many advantages.

Comment: The sap coming out from trees is the way they are sharing the curse. Now you may ask "But sap is nutritional to trees", in that sense even the menstrual blood was also body blood flowing in veins necessary for life, deserts can also be used to collect solar energy, and tidal power of rivers can be used for energy production. So this way even women, rivers and earth also not share any curse.

Comment: @AnuragSingh not nutritional to plants but to us humans... there is no curse

Comment: @Rakesh yes, whatever it is. Sap has many medicinal uses, in Rajasthan Sap us used to make "Gond ke laddoo" , in mountains people use sap for fire as it burns easily for long time,  et cetera.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What curse did Earth, Water, and Trees get by taking Indra's sin of Brahmahatya of Viśvarūpa upon themselves?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22448/what-curse-did-earth-water-and-trees-get-by-taking-indras-sin-of-brahmahatya)

Comment: Not every sap is sharing the guilt, but just some of the sap. See the answer at  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24099/2790