# Pooja during Menstrual period, Hindu Brahmin

Tags: brahmins

We had a big argument y'day at hour house over pooja during Menstrual period.

My wife wanted to do Sravan somvar rituals during her 3rd day of period. She cooked Kheer and wanted to put it as a Prasad in front of God. She actually asked my mom to put the prasad in Mandir. Since my mom knew she is on her periods she said this is not right thing to do as its against ritual and not to perform any pooja or put prsad in front of god. This turned into very heated argument between both of them. My mom was very adamant about her not to perform rituals and my wife's response was I never object your ways when you perform pooja so please let me do it my way!

Usually, its not a problem for me as I think as long as you perform pooja with good intentions, you could do it as the way you want. However, my mom is visiting us for couple of months and I understand her point. I took my mom's side and told my wife to skip rituals this week. She could do it the way she wants when mom is not here. My wife was really mad at my behaviour.

I was thinking all night if I took the right stand?

My wife was arguing about where in Hinduism its mentioned that Women are not supposed do Pooja during menstruation?

**Overall, Gist of all my writing is, I would like to know if female is allowed to perform Pooja rituals at home during menstruation period?**

Thanks.

Comment: What are your exact questions please highlight them.

Comment: "What you people would have done if you were in my place?" We are not a discussion forum. Just Q&A. If you are asking a question, then ask it. If you are asking for opinions, we don't entertain them. Visit help center for more details..

Comment: You should ask question. As said by SS, Stack Exchange is not discussion forum, it is site with Q&A. Edit the question accordingly, else question may be closed.

Comment: Thanks guys, I edited and highlight my question now. I apologize if this has already been discussed before.

Comment: @sanforyou Wait for a while I may post an answer soon.

Comment: Must not be done. The woman in question must isolate herself and not come in contact with others, even more so if they are doing poojas and vratas. Religion is not a matter of opinion or convenience. If people do not want to follow the rules of the religion and worship, they have no right to worship the gods of the religion. People don't go into operation theatres without scrubbing themselves thoroughly. Nor do they enter a mosque with shoes on. Hindu gods are the only ones taken for granted even by hindus.

Answer (score 2):

Your mom was correct, and you took the correct stand by supporting her. Even if your mom is not at your home, that is the correct stand, and you should not ask your wife to do puja during her periods.

During menstruation for 4 days, rituals and puja are not allowed for women - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17620/4435

First appreciate your wife's devotion to God. Not many young women nowadays evince much interest in spiritual matters.

Then ask your wife "Did you see God yourself.. if not, who told you that God exists and that you should do puja for him?"
She will reply "My parents, elders etc."
Then tell her "Ask those same people if it is ok to do puja during menstruation"

If your parents say "Krishna existed and he was dark complexion", and you say "I didn't see Krishna, so I don't believe he exists", then that is scientific.

But if you say "I didn't see Krishna, I believe he exists, but I don't believe he is dark complexsion", then that is not scientific, because you are choosing to believe part of it based on faith and to disbelieve another part of it based on your own limited intellect. No proper scientist would do that.

Krishna, through shastras and acharyas has given us guidelines on how to live life. Playing the game of life according rules set by the referee will give you desired outcomes. If you start to question the referee you'll get red card no matter how much you argue.

Comment: In some families, woman who has periods are not allowed into Pooja room and other family members will do Pooja and  she won't take active part in Pooja related activities (as all activities happen in Pooja room).

Comment: @TheDestroyer is this a question or a statement ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi my statement?  it is statement. I was telling him how some families perform poojas even if some  woman of family is on periods.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi what otherwise? What i said is correct. Menstruating woman alone is excluded in family and others perform pooja on all days.

Comment: @TheDestroyer active part means? then what use of having it

Answer (score 0):

I was about to comment but I don't have privilege to do so..
You are right at your place but, different people do different things in different situations. Some are dear son some are dear husband. But if you really want to be sure that you are on right side then you should try to find an answer "is it really right to do that ritual or not " in broader perspective that is if it really is okk then take your wife's side and if you think that if it not okk then take your mom's side. So your first task will be to decide whether it is really okk or not.

And my view is "phle k samay me yagya aur agni se door rhne k liye (qki ese samay me rest ki jarurat hoti h ) to kaam se bhi aram mile isliye ye sab rituals banaye gye per unka roop esa ban gya h ki jese koi galat kaam krne wale ka bahishkaar kr deta h "
So I myself think that it is not a right thing to do with girls...if they want to .. you should let her do it,and don't oppose her,since for a good prayer you just need a good heart and peaceful mind. :)

Comment: 1. Answers must be in English. 2. Rules are not subject to convenience or personal opinion.

Comment: It's not my fault ,the questions was about "what is your personal opinion" . And my English is not that well ,if you can translate then please do but I can't that's why I wrote it in "___".

Comment: Welcome to HSE. Your English is good. Don't worry. Just cite references with whatever translation/English you can make. We strive for good content answer rather than with a good English.