# What curse did Earth, Water, and Trees get by taking Indra's sin of Brahmahatya of Viśvarūpa upon themselves?

Tags: indra, women, curse

I learnt that women got menstruation for taking 1/4th of Indra's sin of Brahmahatya. What curse did the other three entities get?

Comment: What is the difference b/w Earth and Land. I believe instead of Land it should be Trees. And curse is also similar like milk oozing out from Trees, cracks in Earth, unbalanced waves in Ocean etc.

Comment: My mistake. I meant the trees.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is partially addressed here in this [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17616/were-women-cursed-with-menstruation) .

The story of Indra killing Vishwroopa is described in Bhagavatam Canto 6.

**Curse for Earth/Land:[SB 6.9.7](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/9/7)**

> In return for King Indra’s benediction that ditches in the earth would
>   be filled automatically, the land accepted one fourth of the sinful
>   reactions for killing a brāhmaṇa. **Because of those sinful reactions,
>   we find many deserts on the surface of the earth.**

**Curse for trees:[SB 6.9.8](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/9/8)**

> In return for Indra’s benediction that their branches and twigs would
>   grow back when trimmed, the trees accepted one fourth of the reactions
>   for killing a brāhmaṇa. **These reactions are visible in the flowing of
>   sap from trees. [Therefore one is forbidden to drink this sap.]**

**Curse for water:[SB 6.9.10](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/9/10)**

> And in return for King Indra’s benediction that water would increase
>   the volume of other substances with which it was mixed, water accepted
>   one fourth of the sinful reactions. **Therefore there are bubbles and
>   foam in water. When one collects water, these should be avoided.**

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It  helped clarify my question.

Comment: Can you please explain me the curse for tress? I'm unable to understand what this verse is saying.

Comment: @KrishnaShweta The liquid which comes out of stem of tree when stem is damaged by a weapon is due to Indra's sin.

Comment: 'Therefore one is forbidden to drink this sap'--wherefrom is this part coming? Its not in the text.Is it mentioned in some other scripture? The translation by MBD does not write this partvat all BTW.

Comment: @pratimaputra that they have added. Thats why its in bracket.