# Where in scriptures are menstruating women not allowed to do bhakti?

Tags: women, bhakti, reference-request, menstruation

Is it mentioned anywhere in scriptures (with reasoning if possible) that women cannot pray during menstruation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Were women cursed with menstruation?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17616/were-women-cursed-with-menstruation)

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for other scriptural references.

Comment: true bhakti (bhavana or feeling in heart) surpasses all rules. but what you and I call bhakti is more of ritual or chanting shlok or mantra or bhajan or reading scriptures - which do have rules. forget these devotional stuff, menstruating women are not even supposed to take bath (cos they used to bathe in rivers which would pollute them), or cook food. without basic cleanliness, how can they do bhakti. they're supposed to rest and recuperate during those 3 days, no need for any duties.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think so that it has been mentioned so anywhere. However in Mahabharatha, we have a reference- After Dharmaraja looses in the gambling, Duryodhana orders Dussasana to bring Draupadi to the sabha. She was on her period at that time. She mentions the same to Dussasana and asks her to leave alone as she must not be touched during that time. However she prays to Krishna as Dussasana tries to remove her clothes. Prayer is never denied - a woman can alway pray to God - as in do nama japa of God like sri rama, hare rama hare krishna, siva siva like wise. However, one must not chant any mantras. The same can be seen here in Mahabharatha, where Draupadi prays to Krishna, who infact comes and saves her.

As far as I think of, that is the only mention I can recollect.